# Alarm Manager does not show notification

Tags: android, push-notification, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

There is no error, but just no notification shows up. I tried some various options of the alarm manager but never the notification shows up.

Main Activity:

```
public void startTimer(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 36);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TIMER SET!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

The Toast shows up, so I think the Alarm should work too, but it doesnt.

AlarmReceiver.class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //if we want ring on notifcation then uncomment below line//
//        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).
               // setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo).
                setContentIntent(pendingIntent).
                setContentText("this is my notification").
                setContentTitle("my notificaton").
//                setSound(alarmSound).
        setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());

    }
}
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

 <receiver android:name="world.cryneo.partytime.java.AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="world.cryneo.partytime.java.alarms" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `SET_ALARM` permission is not needed to use `AlarmManager`. However, you do need a `<receiver>` element in the manifest for `AlarmReceiver`. Do you have one? Also, `setRepeating()` is inexact, so it might not fire at the exact time passed.

Comment: I have added the receiver but it still dont work. What should I use instead of setRepeating?

Comment: `setRepeating()` is fine. I was just saying, don't expect it to be exact to the second. Is the Receiver firing at all? Have you put a log print, or a breakpoint there?  Where did you put the `<receiver>` element in the manifest? It goes between the `<application>` tags, but not inside anything else. Also, you do need the `setSmallIcon()` call on the `NotificationCompat.Builder`, so make sure that's un-commented. And, if you're testing on API level 26+, you have to use a channel for the `Notification`. Get the Receiver working first, though.

Comment: Yes the receiver is between <application> . I also uncommented the setSmallIcon but still no success. My app is on API 25. I am not sure about the line    <action android:name="world.cryneo.partytime.java.alarms" /> is this right?

Comment: The `<intent-filter>` is unnecessary, and you should just remove it. It wouldn't cause the current problem, though, so I didn't mention it earlier. You shouldn't be relying on the `Notification`, though, to test the Receiver. Put a log print, or a breakpoint on the first line inside `onReceive()`. Also, you responded relatively quickly, here, so I would assume that you're not really waiting around to give this inexact alarm a chance to fire, if it's a bit off. In that case, during testing, you should temporarily switch to an exact alarm; i.e., use a `setExact*()` method instead.

Comment: It works now. setExact() is better for me. I waited with setRepeating() around 3-4 minutes after It should fire but nothing happend. With setExact the delay is around 30 seconds and than the notification shows up. 
Summarized you were right, there wasnt an error, i was just to impatient. Thanks for your help!